# Is there any way to create viewmodel object in application class?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-mvvm

class DemoApp: Application() {

var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel? = null
override fun onCreate() {

super.onCreate()

loginViewModel=ViewModelProviders.of(applicationContext).get<LoginViewModel(LoginViewModel::class.java)

}

}

Comment: "Is there any way to create viewmodel object in application class?" -- no, sorry.

Comment: i'm not sure if that is possible or not , but what do you want to implement anyway ?

Comment: I want to call api using viewmodel in application class